# How do I make "search this area" the default for a Google Maps search?

Tags: google-maps

This is on a desktop computer. Current/default behavior:

I open Google Maps, it's zoomed in on my location. I zoom out to the whole US and search for something with many instances, let's say "casino" or "McDonald's." The map zooms back in on my current location and shows me nearby McDonald's.

If I then zoom back out to the whole US and click "search this area" (which only appears post-search) then it doesn't zoom back in, but it still prioritizes my location and shows a tiny cluster of McDonald's around it.

Behavior I want:

The initial search ignores my location completely, does not change the zoom level, and shows me all the locations for whatever I searched. (Or if that's impractical, as with McDonald's, then just an evenly distributed sample.)

Choice of browser doesn't seem to matter. Logging out of my Google account doesn't seem to work, and denying location permissions doesn't work either. (I assume it uses the IP address.) Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: As far as I know, google denies this due to performance issues because the result set could simply be too large. Maybe bing maps or another provider can do this.